Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and find the roots of the equation $a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)(x-2)+c(x-2)^2 = 0$.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and find the roots of the equation $a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)(x-2)+c(x-2)^2 = 0$.

My Approach:
Expand the terms in the quadratic equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a(x + 1)^2 &= a(x^2 + 2x + 1) \\
b(x + 1)(x - 2) &= b(x^2 - x - 2) \\
c(x - 2)^2 &= c(x^2 - 4x + 4)
\end{aligned}
$$
This is a quadratic equation of the form
$$
Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0,
$$
where
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
A &= a + b + c, \\
B &= 2a - b - 4c, \\
C &= a - 2b + 4c. 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
It was not quite obvious what I should do after this.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Quadratic Equation- Calculating roots using a given equation.

Here is perhaps a simpler way to solve this without getting into too many equations. Suppose $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. We are given $f(\alpha)=0$ and $f(\beta)=0$.
We define,
$$g(x)=(x-2)^2\, f\left(\frac{x+1}{x-2}\right), \quad \text{ where } x \neq 2.$$
Observe that $g(x)$ represents the left side of the equation given in your problem statement whose roots we want to determine. Suppose $x_1, x_2$ are the roots of $g$. Then,
$$g(x_1)=0 \quad \implies (x_1-2)^2\, f\left(\frac{x_1+1}{x_1-2}\right) \implies \quad \frac{x_1+1}{x_1-2}=\alpha.$$
This gives us $x_1=\dfrac{2\alpha +1 }{\alpha-1}$. Likewise, we get the second root $x_2=\dfrac{2\beta+1}{\beta-1}$.

For the first equation, we can write:
$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a}$$
$$\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$$
And for the second equation, we can divide all the three coefficients $A$, $B$ and $C$ by $a$ to find:
$$A'=\frac Aa=1+\frac ba +\frac ca=1-(\alpha+\beta)+\alpha\beta$$
$$B'=\frac Ba=2-\frac ba-4\frac ca=2-(\alpha+\beta)+4\alpha\beta$$
$$C'=\frac Ca=1-2\frac ba+4\frac ca=1-2(\alpha+\beta)+4\alpha\beta$$
The root of the equation made with the coefficients $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ can be written as:
$$x=\frac{-B'\pm\sqrt{B'^2-4A'C'}}{2A'}$$
Thus, we have every of the roots in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

This method works, but has really long calculation

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$, that means:
$$a(x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$ax - a\alpha x - a\beta x + a\alpha\beta = ax^2 + bx + c$$
Matching up the coefficients, $b = -a(\alpha + \beta)$ and $c = a\alpha\beta$.
Now, let's consider the equation:
$$a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)(x-2)+c(x-2)^2 = 0$$
Plugging in the values of $b$ and $c$ gives.
$$a(x+1)^2-a(\alpha + \beta)(x+1)(x-2)+a\alpha\beta(x-2)^2 = 0$$
This equation can be factored into:
$$a((x+1)-\alpha (x-2))((x+1) - \beta (x-2)) = 0$$
$$a(x+1-\alpha x + 2\alpha)(x+1 - \beta x + 2\beta) = 0$$
Since $a$ is the leading factor of a quadratic, we can assume that $a \ne 0$.  Thus, one of the following is true:

$x+1-\alpha x + 2\alpha = 0 \implies x = \frac{2\alpha+1}{\alpha-1}$
$x+1 - \beta x + 2\beta = 0 \implies x = \frac{2\beta + 1}{\beta - 1}$

Thus, the roots of the equation are $\boxed{\frac{2\alpha+1}{\alpha-1}}$ and $\boxed{\frac{2\beta + 1}{\beta - 1}}$.
